# Custom Panel didn't render well

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I'm trying to customize the rendering of an ASP.NET Panel in this way...

```
 [DefaultProperty("ID")]
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:NFormPanel runat=server></{0}:NFormPanel>")]
    [Description("Aldammam panel.")]
    [ParseChildren(false)]
    [PersistChildren(true)]
    public class NFormPanel : Panel, INamingContainer
    {


        protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("<table class=\"con-table\" style=\"width: 100%;\">");
            output.Write(sb.ToString());
            if (HasControls())
            {

                this.RenderChildren(output);
            }
            sb.Clear();
            sb.AppendLine("</table>");
            output.Write(sb.ToString());

        }


    }
```

...but the output renders the panel controls first then renders the table, like this...

```
 <div>
   <input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1">
   <table class="con-table" style="width: 100%;">
   </table>
 </div>
```

I would like the child controls inside the table as in the example below...

```
<div>
  <table class="con-table" style="width: 100%;">
    <input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1">
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the render method instead:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
{
     var sb = new StringBuilder();
     sb.AppendLine("<table class=\"con-table\" style=\"width: 100%;\">");
     output.Write(sb.ToString());

     if (HasControls())
     {
         //Alternatively call base.Render() which renders the panel's DIV
         this.RenderChildren(output); //renders inner children only without panel DIV
     }

     sb.Clear();
     sb.AppendLine("</table>");
     output.Write(sb.ToString());

}
```

Comment: Sorry, my code sample was wrong; look at the updated sample above.  It overrides the Render method instead.

Comment: Huh, that works for me.  Not sure what to say now.  I've normally not used the StringBuilder, but just used `output.Write("<table ..>");`, I don't know if that would make a difference.